# jQuery call function from added class to call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a multi select plugin to create a goods & services list to be selected. The user will select from a list the services they want, and since there are a lot of services, they are in groups. So the dynamically created content looks like

```
<ul class="ms-optgroup">
  <li class="ms-optgroup-label"><span>Class 41</span></li>
  <li class="ms-elem-selectable"><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li class="ms-elem-selectable"><span>Item 2</span></li>
  <li class="ms-elem-selectable"><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li class="ms-elem-selectable"><span>Item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on an item, it will go to an adjacent list to the right, which all works fine. It then adds a price of $350 to the total for every one clicked. But I want to make a situation where it only adds $350 ONCE no matter how many item's are added.

So I tried making it so when you click on an item, it adds as normal the $350, then adds a class to the ms-optgroup.

```
$(function () {
  addClass(350);
  addService(0);
});

function update() {
    var total = 0;
      $('.ms-selectable .ms-list .ms-optgroup:not(.added) .ms-elem-selectable input[type=hidden], .ms-selectable .ms-list .ms-optgroup.added .ms-elem-selectable input[type=hidden]').each(function () {
        total += +$(this).val();
      });

  $('#variablePrice').text(total);
}

function addClass(value) {
    const elem = $(".ms-selectable .ms-list .ms- optgroup:not(.added) .ms-elem-selectable");
    elem.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('added');
        $(this).append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').val(value));

        update();
      });
}

<ul class="ms-optgroup added">
```

So that all works fine, but then when I go to call a new function for a specific item within a ms-optgroup.added class it just returns the same $350 function 'addClass'

Here is my second function for when ONE item has already been added.

```
function addService(value) {
    const elem = $(".ms-selectable .ms-list .ms-optgroup.added .ms-elem-selectable");

  elem.on('click', function () {
    $(this).append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').val(value));

    update();
  });
}
```

So in my head once the first item has been selected and adds $350, and the ms-optgroup has the classes 'added' the function then called afterwards should only add the value of $0 to for each click.

I hope that makes sense, it's a very specific problem I know. Been trying for awhile to get this right.

Thank you for any help.

Here is a fiddle to show https://jsfiddle.net/uL67gqpc/ So there is two groups as an example, in theory you would add an item from a group and it would add $350 per group, no matter how many items are added. Hence why I tried to add the .added class to prevent further calculation. But I may be way off.

Comment: How can we get that `.val()` to work with your example? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: And what's `<ul class="ms-optgroup added">` doing in your JS??

Comment: I'll get a fiddle going, two ticks

Comment: Fiddle has been added to original post

Comment: And when the values are removed from the right list?.. than... what should happen

Comment: Iwas going to tackle that after I fixed this issue, but it would be the same as the left but in inverse. So when you remove ALL the items in the class (group) it would remove that $350 added. As So removing an item wouldn't effect the total until the last one is removed in that class essentially.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use checkboxes, store the price into a `data-*` attribute and use `Array.reduce()` to calculate the `:checked` one's values

```js
let price = 350; // Or whatever
const $service = $('[name="service[]"]');

const calcTotal = () => {
  const price_services = [...$service.filter(':checked').get()]
    .reduce((v, el) => (v += +el.dataset.value, v), 0);
  const result = price_services ? price_services + price : 0;
  $('#total').text(`${result}$`)
}

$service.on('change', calcTotal).trigger('change');
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; margin:0;}
label {display: block;}
```

```html
<h6>ONE</h6>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='a' data-value="10"> a 10$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='b' data-value="15"> b 15$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='c' data-value="8"> c 8$</label>
<h6>TWO</h6>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='d' data-value="120"> d 120$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='e' data-value="100"> e 100$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='f' data-value="7"> f 7$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='g' data-value="4"> g 4$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='h' data-value="2"> h 2$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='i' data-value="64"> i 64$</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value='j' data-value="33"> j 33$</label>
<h6>TOTAL:</h6>
<span id="total"></span>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have gone to find a solution, but unfortunately I have to work in the constraints of that format provided using the multi select js.